# Windows Mountpoint for a Device

Tags: windows, device, ntfs, mount

I am trying to mount a windows device via ist device path to an ntfs-folder. The device path is in the form:

```
\\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\ImDisk{0}
```

i would like to mount it in an empty ntfs-folder, lets say:

```
c:\temp\
```

The device I try to mount is an ImDisk ram drive, which comes with an api. Essentially the api mounts the device via

```
hDir = CreateFile(Directory, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS |
        FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT, NULL);
```

and then does a

```
DeviceIoControl(hDir, FSCTL_SET_REPARSE_POINT, &ReparseData,
           16 + iSize + 2 + iSize + 2, NULL, 0, &dw, NULL))
```

from all I can see in the msdn this is done correctly. The only problem is: It doesn't work. Whatever device notation I use the created junction can't be opened by the explorer. The junction is created and recognized by the explorer by when I try to open it, explorer tells me that the target syntax is invalid.

So far I have tried to mount the device by addressing it like:

```
\\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\ImDisk0

\\.\GLOBALROOT\Device\ImDisk0

\\.\Device\ImDisk0

\\Device\ImDisk0
```

None of this seems to work.
I am positive that the Ram-Drive exists and is correctly formated. I am able to access it via a Driveletter (if I assign one during it's creation f.e. E:\)

And I can access it via

```
CreateFile("\\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\ImDisk0\file.txt")
```

I can create a FileStream, execute code from it etc.

Any clues how to mount it in a ntfs-folder?
Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Corelgott

Comment: In my experience all the standard reparse point data expects the target to be in the form of `\??\<PATH>` where <PATH> is the drive letter and path of the target.  Can you try `\??\E:\` and see if that works?

Comment: Hi Luke, I just tried you proposed way, but the problem is thatthe api changes my path to \\?\<PATH>, even though DeviceIoControl gets the parameter right, the resulting junktion has the changed path, which, accoring to some sites is a known and intended behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Try...

mklink /d c:\temp \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\ImDisk0\

This can be removed by **rd c:\temp**

Failing that try [DosDev](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adioltean/archive/2005/10/04/477164.aspx).

dosdev x: \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\ImDisk0\

This may be removed by **dosdev -d x:**

While LINKD may be an option on certain legacy systems, a clean install of WinXP SP3 revealed linkd.exe was **not** found:

dir %systemdrive%\linkd.exe /s/a-d/b

Comment: Mklink only exists on Windows Vista and up. Windows 2000/XP users would need to make an NTFS junction point instead via `LINKD Destination Source`. Might add that to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to SuperGQ's answer:

> Try...
>
> mklink /d c:\temp \?\GLOBALROOT\Device\ImDisk0\
>
> Failing that try DosDev (an example of the DefineDosDevice() Win32
>   API)

mklink only exists on Windows Vista and up. Windows 2000/XP users would need to install the [Server 2003 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657) and make an NTFS junction point instead via:

```
LINKD Destination Source
```

More documentation on LINKD and NTFS Junctions: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/205524

Also the remove commands differ a bit in that LINKD contains an inbuilt removal tool:

```
LINKD Source /D
```

While mklink can't remove symbolic links. Something like:

```
fsutil reparsepoint delete PATH
```

Is required.

Specifically, `mklink` exists on Windows 8, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2012, Windows Vista, and Windows 7 (though, oddly enough, Window 7 is not listed in the technet documentation http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx)